# Error: Program type already present: com.example.library.BuildConfig

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I've startet to write a library project in Kotlin with the package `com.example.library` .. This library is free of any android stuff and I use there libraries like:

- Moshi
- Fuel
- Mockito
- JUnit

Including this library in my example app, leads to

> Program type already present: com.example.library.BuildConfig
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.example.library.BuildConfig, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

I've read os far, the cause is a redundand definition for `com.example.library.BuildConfig`..

In project view I go External Libraries and browse to `mylib` and unfold until I reach `BuildConfig` with decompiled:

```
package com.example.library;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final String VERSION = "0.0.0-rc.126.37";
    public static final String NAME = "mylib-api";

    private BuildConfig() {
    }
}
```

How can I find the other redundant part? How can I solve this?

Info1:

The gradle.properties of my lib says: 
`group=com.example.library`

The gradle.properties of my app says:
`group=com.example.mylib-demo`

Comment: I bet you have your library also as a jar file in your lib folder? Check `your_project/your_module/lib`and delete corresponding jar file

Comment: Thanks @MuratCeven ! your comment should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate library, also as a jar file in your lib folder.
Check `your_project/your_module/lib` and delete corresponding jar file